# NoReverseMatch in django with kwargs

Tags: django

I'm having trouble getting the `{% url %}` tag to work with a django view. When visiting the site I get the error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /betalinger/

Reverse for 'confirm' with keyword arguments '{'plan': ''}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['betalinger/confirm/', 'betalinger/confirm/(?P<plan>.+)/$']
```

It complains about not finding the url with a keyword argument, but at least one of the urls accepts the `plan` keyword.

**`urls.py`**:

```
...
url(regex=r'^confirm/(?P<plan>.+)/$', view=ConfirmFormView.as_view(), name='confirm'),
url(regex=r'^confirm/', view=ConfirmFormView.as_view(), name='confirm'),
...
```

And the template making noise:

```
<html>
...
    <form action="{% url 'payments:confirm' plan=plan.plan %}">
...
</html>
```

Comment: You need to show your template context. What is `plan` here, and does it have a `plan` attribute that is not empty?

Comment: You should have different names for the URLs. `<plan>` will match any character, also space. Are you really sure about that? Maybe you need `(?P<plan>[\w-]+)`. That will match any alphanumerical character and the hyphen.

Comment: You need a dollar at the end of your second regex: `r'^confirm/$`. While it's OK to write `url(regex=r'^confirm/...)`, I don't think I've ever seen `regex` as a keyword argument before. Use `url(r'^confirm/...)` so that it doesn't look unusual to other Django developers.

Comment: @DanielRoseman  Plan is a string, im not completely sure it is empty or filled. Can that be the reason?

Comment: @cezar it is actually ok to use `name='confirm'` in both URL patterns. Django will use the one that matches the args/kwargs provided.

Comment: Well, yes, if `plan` is a string why are you trying to access `plan.plan`?

Comment: @Alasdair Thats how our style is laid out in the whole project. I can't commit changes everywhere and i'm not gonna make this one `urls.py` stand out

Comment: @DanielRoseman Sorry. `Plan.plan` is a string. `Plan` is a django model object(we're looping over different payment plans)

Comment: Fair enough. The missing dollar is a separate issue, you should fix that anyway.

Comment: Fair enough. But yes, if `plan.plan` is an empty string it will not match the regex `(?P<plan>.+)` which requires at least one character.

Comment: @Alasdair Fixed ;)

Comment: @DanielRoseman That worked. Do you want to make that an answer to get some reputation